# Add/Append query string if empty jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I append a query string such as `?a=0` on document ready? It must first check if there is an existing query string. It should only append the query string if there isn't one there already. Otherwise, it should do nothing.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Duplicate question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: You may be able to reference: [Append to URL and Refresh Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997450/append-to-url-and-refresh-page)

Comment: Perhaps take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656843/jquery-get-querystring-from-url

Comment: if you have apache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210412/htaccess-301-redirect-if-no-query-string-present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( !window.location.search.trim().length ) 
   window.location.href = window.location.href + '?a=0';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!(window.location.search.indexOf("?a=0") > -1)) {
    window.location.href += window.location.search;
}
```

Comment: @user1610812 - great. glad to help. Please upvote all helpful answers and accept one as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    url = window.location;  //get current url
    if(url.indexOf("?a=") == -1){ //check for ?a= 
     document.location = url+"?a=0"; // redirect it
    }

});
```